# Add Tooltips to helper html.dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I have a dropdownlist that displays just products codes *101,102,103*

If the user hovers over a product code I would like the title to appear as a tooltip.

So it's not your normal DataValue & DataText scenerio, because "101" would be both the display text & the value.

I believe I will need to use jQuery to achive this effect.
And I also believe I would need to set the Title attribute of each list item as the Product Title.

**My question is, using helper html.dropdownlist how can I set the title attribute?**

Thanks, this is my first day using MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used tipsy once for something very similar.  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy

We actually took it a step further and "created" an attribute like this

```
<span class="tipsyItem" tipsy="This is my tooltip text!">This is my regular text!</span>
```

The reason was that tipsy would still show the regular tooltip on occasion.  We used some of the advanced settings like this.

```
$('.tipsyItem').tipsy({title: 'tipsy'});
```

Plus you can theme it.  Also were even able to get it to support html embedded in the tooltips for links and such.

```
$('.tipsyItem').tipsy({html: true });
```

Twitter used to use tipsy.  I'm not sure if they still do.

Comment: It looks like it can be applied to the dropdown list as a whole, but not PER list item.

Comment: I think for what you want to do you may have to look at a custom solution, such as adapting an autocomplete to work like a drop down.  I know in that instance you could get it to work by defining each item format shown in the autocomplete.